# UIScreen screens always return 1 screen

Tags: xcode, mirroring, ipad-2, airplay

I'm trying to display a picture on Apple TV with Airplay without mirroring mode. But [UIScreen screens] method always return 1 screen (main screen) when mirroring is OFF.
I want my picture display same as Photo application (Airplay without mirroring).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidConnect:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidDisconnect:) name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
```

I used them, but they only work when Mirroring is ON.

Please help me. Thanks so much!
I'm using Apple TV1 and iPad 2 (iOS 5.0.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's a bit misleading, indeed. You should proceed as follows:

- Airplay mirroring option should be ON
- then, you create a new `UIWindow` and attach it to the second screen
- as soon as you send makeKeyAndVisible to this new `UIWindow`, it overrides mirroring and shows new content.
- You may add views or a root view controller as in the main part of application

Here's the code:

```
UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:secondScreen.bounds];
[self.secondWindow setScreen:secondScreen];
[self.secondWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.secondWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Additionally, you cannot enable AirPlay mirroring from within your app.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786080/how-can-i-turn-on-airplay-screen-mirroring-on-the-iphone-4s-programmatically